# DOSBox run command at start

Tags: dos, autostart, dosbox

Is there a way to run a command after DOSBox ist started automatically?
Or is there maybe a way with a batch script or something like this?

I want to automate these commands:

```
mount c: c:/
c:
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AUTOEXEC.BAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in AUTOEXEC.BAT file. Check [this](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/AUTOEXEC).